# Multivariable Split Testing frameworks

Tags: ab-testing

Does anyone know of any open source software that is designed for running split tests on server side code.

Answer (score 1):

I know of a few FOSS multivariate testing tools. I'm not sure if they'll meet your needs.

- [Genetify](https://github.com/gregdingle/genetify/wiki) - javaScript tool. I've used this a couple of times and have been pleased with it.
- [Vanity](http://vanity.labnotes.org/) - Rails tool
- [A/Bingo](http://www.bingocardcreator.com/abingo) - Rails tool
- [Seven Minute Abs](https://github.com/paulmars/seven_minute_abs) - Rails tool
- [DIY](http://www.tonylegrone.com/the-tech/diy-ab-split-testing-using-php-and-mysql) - Article showing how to build your own with PHP & MySQL (code included).